# How do I validate configuration with the automapper Instance API

Tags: c#, automapper

I know that using automapper's static API I can do this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());

Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

but now I've switched to the instance API:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

How/where can I check if the configuration is valid using the instance API?

Comment: `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`?

Comment: So simple when you know how..... thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also do the validation using:

```
mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```